# OpenGL Orthographic Projection and Translate

Tags: opengl-es, orthographic

The code below draws a rectangle in 2D screen space using OpenGL ES2. How do move the drawing of the rectangle by 1 pixel to the right without modifying its vertices?

Specifically, what I am trying to do is move the coordinates 0.5 pixels to the right. I had to do this previously with GLES1.x and the reason for this is that I had problems drawing lines in the correct place unless I did a glTranslate() with 0.5f.

I'm confused about the use of glm::translate() in the code below.

If I attempt a translate of 0.5f, the whole rectangle moves from the left of the screen to the middle - a jump of about 200 pixels.

I get the same result whether I do a glm::translate on the Model or the View matrix.

Is the order of the matrix multiplication wrong and what should it be?

```
short g_RectFromTriIndices[] =
{
  0, 1, 2,
  0, 2, 3

}; // The order of vertex rendering.

GLfloat g_AspectRatio = 1.0f;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LoadTwoTriangleVerticesForRect()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LoadTwoTriangleVerticesForRect( GLfloat *pfRectVerts, float fLeft, float fTop, float fWidth, float fHeight )
{
  pfRectVerts[  0 ] = fLeft;
  pfRectVerts[  1 ] = fTop;
  pfRectVerts[  2 ] = 0.0;

  pfRectVerts[  3 ] = fLeft + fWidth;
  pfRectVerts[  4 ] = fTop;
  pfRectVerts[  5 ] = 0.0;

  pfRectVerts[  6 ] = fLeft + fWidth;
  pfRectVerts[  7 ] = fTop  + fHeight;
  pfRectVerts[  8 ] = 0.0;

  pfRectVerts[  9 ] = fLeft;
  pfRectVerts[ 10 ] = fTop  + fHeight;
  pfRectVerts[ 11 ] = 0.0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Draw()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Draw( void )
{
  GLfloat afRectVerts[ 12 ];

  //LoadTwoTriangleVerticesForRect( afRectVerts, 0, 0, g_ScreenWidth, g_ScreenHeight );
  LoadTwoTriangleVerticesForRect( afRectVerts, 50, 50, 100, 100 );

  // Correct for aspect ratio so squares ARE squares and not rectangular stretchings..
  g_AspectRatio = (GLfloat) g_ScreenWidth / (GLfloat) g_ScreenHeight;

  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

  GLuint hPosition = glGetAttribLocation( g_SolidProgram, "vPosition" );

  // PROJECTION
  glm::mat4 Projection = glm::mat4(1.0);
  //  Projection = glm::perspective( 45.0f, g_AspectRatio, 0.1f, 100.0f );

  // VIEW
  glm::mat4 View = glm::mat4(1.0);

  static GLfloat transValY = 0.5f;
  static GLfloat transValX = 0.5f;

  //View = glm::translate( View, glm::vec3( transValX, transValY, 0.0f ) );

  // MODEL
  glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0);

  //  static GLfloat rot = 0.0f;

  //  rot += 0.001f;
  //  Model = glm::rotate( Model, rot, glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) ); // where x, y, z is axis of rotation (e.g. 0 1 0)

  glm::mat4 Ortho = glm::ortho( 0.0f, (GLfloat) g_ScreenWidth, (GLfloat) g_ScreenHeight, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1000.0f );

  glm::mat4 MVP;

  MVP = Projection * View * Model * Ortho;

  GLuint hMVP;

  hMVP = glGetUniformLocation( g_SolidProgram, "MVP" );
  glUniformMatrix4fv( hMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( MVP ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( hPosition );

  // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
  glVertexAttribPointer( hPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, FALSE, 0, afRectVerts );

  // Draw the rectangle using triangles
  glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, g_RectFromTriIndices );

  glDisableVertexAttribArray( hPosition );
}
```

Here is the vertex shader source:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = MVP * vPosition;
}
```

UPDATE: I'm finding the below matrix multiplication is giving me better results. I don't know if this is "correct" or not though:

```
MVP = Ortho * Model * View * Projection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That MVP seems really weird to me, you shouldn't need 4 things in there to get your MVP.. your Projection matrix should just be the Orthogonal one, so in this case

`MVP = Projection * View * Ortho;`

But I can also see that your Projection matrix has been commented from perspective so I don't think it's doing much right now.

By the sounds of it since you want the model co-ordinates to stay the same while moving, you want to move your camera right? So (By the looks of it your vertices are using a 1 unit per pixel co-ordinate range) doing a translate of 0.5f to your View is shifting whatever half your projection space is. Instead, you want to have something like a `Camera` class that you get your `View`from using the camera's `X` and `Y` positions.

Then you can get your View matrix using the cameras position which can share the world units system you're using, which is 1 unit per pixel.

```
glm::mat4 view;
view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(camX, camY, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
```

I ripped that line straight (minus changing camZ for camY) from a really good 3d tutorial on camera [here](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera) but the exact same concept can be applied to a orthogonal camera instead

I know it's a bit more overhead but having a cmaera class that you can control this way is nicer practice than manually using glm::translate,rotate&scale to control your viewport (and it lets you ensure that you'r working with a more obivous co-ordinate system between your camera and models co-ordinate points.